# On what combinations of Chrome/Safari, desktop/mobile, and normal/incognito does localStorage work?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, local-storage

I know this may depend on browser version, but hoping for answers 'in general' or 'recent browser versions'.  This is my current theory.  Can anyone confirm or correct it?

1. Chrome - desktop - normal - YES
2. Chrome - desktop - incognito - YES
3. Chrome - mobile - normal - YES
4. Chrome - mobile - incognito - NO
5. Safari - desktop - normal - YES
6. Safari - desktop - incognito - NO
7. Safari - mobile - normal - NO
8. Safari - mobile - incognito - NO

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is *supposed* to work whether you're in incognito mode or not. The main thing is, it's not supposed to *transfer* between private mode and normal mode. However, this isn't always followed, and mobile browsers don't follow the rules very well.

You can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/engelfrost/fd707819658f72b42f55) to get around LocalStorage restrictions.